# Github pages .io as API , Rate limit

Tags: json, api, github, github-pages

I am making a android app which will have around 1-2k users per day, all I need is a json file which is hosted on https://name.github.io/repo/filename.json.

Is their any limitations on doing so?

Is their any better way to host this json file to fetch the data?
I will be also updating this json from time to time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub doesn't consider using using GitHub Pages as a CDN for hosting static assets to be [within its guidelines for GitHub Pages](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#guidelines-for-using-github-pages).  The intended purpose is to host a personal blog or website or a website for your open source project.

The documentation linked above outlines acceptable uses and limits.

Instead, you could end up storing this JSON file in some sort of cloud bucket (e.g., S3), possibly with a CDN (e.g., Cloudflare) in front of it.  That would probably keep costs minimal for your app.